# Springsource Tool suite does not reflect JSP, CSS and Javascript changes w/o redeploying the web application

Tags: jsp, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

We are using Springsource tool suite for the application development. But whenever we make any changes in the JSP, CSS or Javascript we have to redeploy the application, then only we can see our changes in the browser.

This is unlike MyEclipse which reflects such changes immidiately(No need to redeploy).

Is there any solution for this?

JRebel is costly so not thinking of JRebel as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying static resources without redeploys works totally fine in STS with Dynamic Web Proect. In server configuration screen, in 'Server locations' section, in 'Publishing' section you better set the option to automatically publish the changes, and check if the option is set to 'Use workspace metadata' and at the 'Modules' tab for the server configuration the automatic redeploys are disabled for the app (in case of Tomcat).

With such project type and setup the app is deployed in exploded mode. Probably you have a maven project and that prevents the resources from  being updated?